# Angular JS Tutorial: How does /index.html redirects to /index#!/phones? [See description]

Tags: angularjs

In [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

> When you now navigate to /index.html, you are redirected to
> /index.html#!/phones and the phone list appears in the browser.

Where is it configured, to redirect `/index.html` to `/index.html#!/phones` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you continue reading the tutorial you will find this section **Configuring a Module** and here the tutorial talks about ngRoute and hte config file **app/app.config.js**.

In this file you configure your routes, so with this:

```
angular.
  module('phonecatApp').
  config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
      $routeProvider.
        when('/phones', {
          template: '<phone-list></phone-list>'
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
          template: '<phone-detail></phone-detail>'
        }).
        otherwise('/phones');
    }
  ]);
```

You can see that no one state has the **/** path so it will apply these sentence **otherwise('/phones')** and it will redirect to that url.

Keep in mind that if there is no one match it will go to otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure out the routing going on here. Initially, there is no match, so 'otherwise' section is picked; just after this, it will match "when('/phones',..." from which the template is picked.

Comment: yes, that is. Initially the otherwise section is picked so it will go to the phones-list template (/phones state).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [App Config](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-9/app/app.config.js)

`$routeProvider.
        when('/phones', {
          template: '<phone-list></phone-list>'
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
          template: '<phone-detail></phone-detail>'
        }).
        otherwise('/phones');
    }`

In this case case when you go to '/' no mapping is configured ,so it goes to `otherwise('/phones')`;

Answer (score 1):

you have to find function responsible for routing. Look at *app.config.js* file.
Suggestion: In bigger applications good practise is separating routing for each module in single file.